# how to continue a function without waiting for completion of called function in C#

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a dispatcher function in my code which call another function at some particular time as follow :-

```
private void timer_startTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Target10 currentTime = this;
        currentTime.CurrentTime = currentTime.CurrentTime - 1;
        this.txttimer.Text = string.Concat("0 : ", Convert.ToString(this.CurrentTime));
        if(CurrentTime == 0)
            timer_startTimer.Stop();
        if (CuurentTime == 10)
        {
            getResult();
        }

    }
```

As mentioned in above code my function `timer_startTimer_Tick` will call the function `getResult` at 10 sec. Function `getResult()` will take some time to be completed. How can I continue my parent function `timer_startTimer_Tick` without waiting for completion of `getResult` function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use Threads objects to do the job.

define:

```
private Thread thread;
private Queue<Action> queue; // The Action Queue
```

Put the code above in your class constructor:

```
 thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate {
     while (true)
     {
         if (queue.Count > 0)
             queue.Dequeue()(); //This command takes the function of the queue and executes it
     }
 }));
 queue = new Queue<Action>(); // Instanciate the queue
 thread.Start();
```

In his timer, instead of calling the function , place it in queue:

```
...
if (CuurentTime == 10)
{
    queue.Enqueue(getResult); //no parenthesis
}
...
```

Or You can use Async Methods. Take a look at this sites:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/async

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/591586/Asynchronous-Programming-in-Csharp-using-async

sincerely advise you to know the solution of asynchronous methods

Comment: Luiz : Thanks. What is `queue` here ? Is it a variable ?

Comment: Basically yes . You must declare it in its class, not as a local variable in a function. It works like a list of functions . Your Timer only adds a function to this queue . That effectively renders its function is the thread with the function defined on that delegate inside the constructor . I noticed a mistake I made . You need to test the thread if the queue is not empty I will correct answer.

Comment: Corrected! Pls. if u can, up my answer. Thank's

Comment: Ohh Thanks. One more question I have. What will be the type of this queue? Means If I define it like `private Queue<> queue;`

Comment: Corrected! Again :). Use Queue<Action>

Comment: Luiz : When I implement above code and put the second part of above code in constructor I got `NullReferenceException` everytime I run my program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73605/discussion-between-joao-luiz-grigoletti-and-mohit-gupta).

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the method call in a task.

```
Task.Run(() => getResult());
```

Comment: Thanks Sir ! When I implement this I am getting error at `Run` . i.e. `can not resolve symbol Run`

Comment: Which version of .Net are you targeting?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Task` (import System.Threading.Task) or some implementation of the async/await pattern. The simplest way is way is `Task.Run(() => getResult());` which will start `getResult()` in the background.

Comment: I tried this method but I am getting error at `Run` i.e. `can not resolve symbol Run` . When i searched over the web regarding this error nothing found because according to every article implementing `Threading.Task` is enough and `Task.Run` is an method of this class. But I don't know whats wrong with me.